# Computing projection matrices in J

Tags: matrix, j

I'm trying to compute a projection matrix in J. That is, given the matrix `A`, I want to compute `A(A'A)^(-1)A'`, where `A'` is the transpose of `A`.

I think the right way to do this is to note that I'm doing three operations to `A` and multiplying the results. I'm looking for something like `(f x) * (g x) * (h x)` if `f`, `g`, and `h` are verbs. (Accounting for `+/ . *` being matrix multiplication.) Is there a J construct or idiom to do this concisely? Or is there an altogether better way to do this in J?

My rough work so far:

```
mp =: +/ . *
ATA =: |: mp ]
right_proj =: (%.@ATA) mp |: NB. (A'A)^(-1)A factor in product.
proj_mat =: ] mp right_proj
```

Comment: If it matters, you can use a QR (`128!:0`) or SVD decomposition from the library 'math/lapack'. Then A(A'A)^(-1)A' = QQ' or UU'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution is pretty good. My immediate approach would have been very similar:

```
mp=: +/ .*        NB. matrix multiplication
XtY=: mp~ |:      NB. sum of cross products (monadic is XtX)
proj_mat=: mp %.@XtY mp |:
```

However an alternative is possible using dyadic `%.` which may generate numerically better results. It relies on the fact that `y %. X` is equivalent to `X'X^(-1)X'y`. If we define a verb to create an identity matrix we can use `%.` to get most of the way - just need to pre-multiply by X.

```
I=: =@i.@#                 NB. identity matrix
proj_mat=: mp I %. ]       NB. projection matrix
```

The results are not exactly the same as the first approach but I think they'll be more similar to a LAPACK solution.

Comment: Do you have a source for the equivalency you mention? The J vocabulary page for the dyadic `%.` mentions minimizing a distance relevant to projection, but I wouldn't have guessed that using a matrix instead of a vector does the same thing.

Comment: The following page suggests that equivalency in the more information section. http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/percentdot#dyadic